# Should I use directive instead of ng-include if there is too much in onLoad

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a partial template called `card.html`. Im using it on many pages and some of these pages shouldn't include all the details. Because of that Im passing variables like `showDetails=false; isBig=true; hideDuration=true;` and also if Im using that partial outside of ng-repeat passing the card data as `card=cardData` on the onLoad parameter.

Now Im considering should I make it as a directive to make things clear or there is no problem  with kind a usage of onLoad.

**UPDATE:**

Here is the most complex usage for the partial.

```
<div class="div"
      ng-class="{done: takenPicture}"
      ng-include="'js/modules/game/templates/card.html'"
      onLoad="hideDuration = true; bigCard = true; showDetails = true; card = selectedCard"> 
</div>
```

Comment: It's funny you should ask. In our project in the beginning we went crazy making directives. Later we found that a bunch of them just did nothing more than load templates. We went through and changed to using ng-include instead. I think I would leave it the way you have it.

Comment: Yeah thats what Im asking for :D I don't want to create dummy directives doing nothing but loading a template. And you guys experienced reverse :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any problem using the ng-include directive as you are, although I'm unsure how you are passing the variables. The position of the ng-include element will direct which variables it has access to by borrowing from its parent scope.

Comment: Ah damn yes i can get rid of the cardData variable. But for the other variables (which special to the partial to make hiding and showing details) i don't want mess the $scope with them.